# Set default resource type for attributes on model in c#

Tags: c#, resources, localization

I'm looking for a simpler/drier way to use ressources my MVC 3 models.

This is how I'm doing it now (Each attribute needs to be told which ressource type it uses):

```
    public class ContactMessageModel:BaseModel
    {
        [Display(Name="ReplyToEmail_DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(Res.Views_Contact))]
        public string ReplyToEmail {get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ContactReason_DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(Res.Views_Contact))]
        public string ContactReason { get; set; }
```

Can this be done?

This is how I'd like to do it (I just want to define the resource type for the model once):

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Res.Views_Contact))]
public class ContactMessageModel:BaseModel
{
    [Display(Name="ReplyToEmail_DisplayName")]
    public string ReplyToEmail {get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ContactReason_DisplayName")]            
    public string ContactReason { get; set; }
```

Comment: err yes :). Gives me an Error: Attribute 'Display' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, param' declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem possible, because the attribute instance would require access to the property it is sitting on, which .NET does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, defaulting the ResourceType can be done. Phil Haack shows an example of how to override .NET's ModelMetadataProviders to accomplish this and prevent having to repeat yourself specifying the same ResourceType over and over:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx/

You can either default to a single ResourceType globally, or decorate specific classes with a default using this attribute he defines:

```
public class MetadataConventionsAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ResourceType { get; set; }
}
```